# How Can I add This jQuery Twice to the Same Page?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add this code, generated by a WordPress plugin, to the same page twice - but it won't generate the countdown timer the second time.... Is there a simple change I could make to make it appear twice?

THANKS!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var austDay = new Date("2012/02/11 00:00");
    jQuery.countdown.regional["uji"] = {
        labels: ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"],
        labels1: ["Year", "Month", "Week", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"],
        compactLabels: ["A", "L", "S", "Z"],
        whichLabels: null,
        timeSeparator: ':',
        isRTL: false
    };
    jQuery.countdown.setDefaults(jQuery.countdown.regional["uji"]);
    jQuery("#ujiCountdown").countdown({until: austDay, text_size: '55', color_down: '#3A3A3A', color_up: '#635b63', color_txt:  '#FFFFFF', color_sw:  '#000000',  ujic_txt: true, animate_sec: true});
    jQuery("#ujiCountdown").css({"width": (jQuery("#ujiCountdown").width()-10)+"px", "padding-left": "30px"});
});
//-->
</script>

<div id="ujiCountdown"  class="ujic_center"></div>
```

Comment: Create another div tag with a separate id and call jQuery(some_id).countdown

Comment: I make the wild assumption that you DO have a closing tag on that div :)

Comment: Why do people still wrap their scripts in comments?! This hasn't been necessary since Netscape4!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get more than one of these on the page you will need to assign the second one to a different DOM element.  Is it possible for you to make a second div with a different ID?  You could then call the jQuery code on the second div and they will both show because they will be different.

```
<div id="ujiCountdown2"></div>
```

and then in the same ready block you can call

```
jQuery("#ujiCountdown2").countdown({until: austDay, text_size: '55', color_down: '#3A3A3A', color_up: '#635b63', color_txt:  '#FFFFFF', color_sw:  '#000000',  ujic_txt: true, animate_sec: true});
```

Comment: note: you could ALSO use a class selector on two divs and only have the code in ONCE (assumption is the options are exactly the same )

Comment: Indeed, that could be a more elegant solution.  If both div's had a class of ujic_center, then the jQuery call would be: 
jQuery(".ujic_center").countdown({until: austDay, text_size: '55', color_down: '#3A3A3A', color_up: '#635b63', color_txt:  '#FFFFFF', color_sw:  '#000000',  ujic_txt: true, animate_sec: true});

Answer (score 0):

The ID would need to change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
                 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    var austDay = new Date("2012/02/11 00:00");
                    jQuery.countdown.regional["uji"] = {
                        labels: ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"],
                        labels1: ["Year", "Month", "Week", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"],
                        compactLabels: ["A", "L", "S", "Z"],
                        whichLabels: null,
                        timeSeparator: ':', isRTL: false};
                    jQuery.countdown.setDefaults(jQuery.countdown.regional["uji"]);
                    jQuery("#ujiCountdown1").countdown({until: austDay, text_size: '55', color_down: '#3A3A3A', color_up: '#635b63', color_txt:  '#FFFFFF', color_sw:  '#000000',  ujic_txt: true, animate_sec: true});  
                    jQuery("#ujiCountdown1").css({"width": (jQuery("#ujiCountdown").width()-10)+"px", "padding-left": "30px"});
                    });
    //-->
    </script><div id="ujiCountdown1"  class="ujic_center">


<script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
                 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    var austDay = new Date("2012/02/11 00:00");
                    jQuery.countdown.regional["uji"] = {
                        labels: ["Years", "Months", "Weeks", "Days", "Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"],
                        labels1: ["Year", "Month", "Week", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"],
                        compactLabels: ["A", "L", "S", "Z"],
                        whichLabels: null,
                        timeSeparator: ':', isRTL: false};
                    jQuery.countdown.setDefaults(jQuery.countdown.regional["uji"]);
                    jQuery("#ujiCountdown2").countdown({until: austDay, text_size: '55', color_down: '#3A3A3A', color_up: '#635b63', color_txt:  '#FFFFFF', color_sw:  '#000000',  ujic_txt: true, animate_sec: true});  
                    jQuery("#ujiCountdown2").css({"width": (jQuery("#ujiCountdown").width()-10)+"px", "padding-left": "30px"});
                    });
    //-->
    </script><div id="ujiCountdown2"  class="ujic_center">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another div - when you run the function the second time, it's still operating on the same div. Add another div:

```
<div id="ujiCountdown2" class="ujic_center"></div>
```

Then in the JS, change the following lines at the bottom of the function:

```
jQuery("#ujiCountdown, #ujiCountdown2").countdown({until: austDay, text_size: '55', color_down: '#3A3A3A', color_up: '#635b63', color_txt:  '#FFFFFF', color_sw:  '#000000',  ujic_txt: true, animate_sec: true});  
jQuery("#ujiCountdown, #ujiCountdown2").css({"width": (jQuery("#ujiCountdown").width()-10)+"px", "padding-left": "30px"});
```

Then the jQuery methods get applied to both divs.